# SQL grouping - throwing out old results

Tags: sql

Some data would be organized thusly:

```
ID DATE COUNT1 COUNT2 
A  20120101 1    2
A  20120201 2    2
B  20120101 3    0
C  20111201 1    0
C  20120301 2    2
```

Another table has     `ID   NAME`

```
               A MYNAME
              .... etc
```

i want to return a table of

```
ID NAME COUNT COUNT2
```

for the most recent available piece of data, i.e. the january count for A is not included

i know I need to use HAVING, INNER JOIN,  and GROUP BY but every iteration I can come up with has an error.

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: @JoeStefanelli he's using nosql

Comment: @user1245973 I don't quite get what you're asking nor what is the `another table` structure. Can you detail both?

Comment: @Mosty I want to return for each unique ID the latest data of counts, along with a NAME associated to the ID through table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want rows with the date equal to the global maximum date, just use a subquery:

```
select ID,DATE,COUNT1,COUNT2
from table
where DATE=(select max(DATE) from table);
```

If you want the maximum date per `ID`, then you can use a self join:

```
select ID,MAX_DATE,COUNT1,COUNT2
from(
    select ID,max(DATE) as MAX_DATE
    from table
    group by ID
)a
join(
    select ID,DATE,COUNT1,COUNT2
    from table
)b
on (a.ID=b.ID and a.MAX_DATE=b.DATE);
```

Comment: That subquery would return the max date for the whole table, not per ID.

Comment: Well, it's not immediately clear that OP wants a per-ID max date.  Lemme edit, however.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. This should also work:

```
select t1.id, t2.name, t1,count1, t1.count2
 from table_1 t1 join table_2 t2 on (t1.id = t2.id)
where not exists (
  select 1
    from table_1 t3
   where t1.id = t3.id
     and t1.date < t3.date)
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Count1, Count2
FROM CountsTable AS T1 INNER JOIN NamesTable ON T1.Id=NamesTable.Id
WHERE CountsTable.Date = (
    SELECT Max(Date) From CountsTable AS T2 WHERE T1.Id=T2.Id
    )
```